# JavaFX adding custom item to Pane

Tags: javafx, pane

I have an FXML file that has a Pane as one of it's entries, used for the output of our program.  I would like to have this Pane contain an HTMLEditor.  I'm a little bit confused at what to do to accomplish this.  The class uses the Singleton pattern as recommended, and I can call into the Controller to get the Pane.

Then I find myself having to create an inner class, since HTMLEditor is not a Node.  So I extended rectangle to do this, and use getChildren.add(htmlEditorWrapper) to try and add it as a Node.  Of course, the HTMLEditor does not show up when I run the program.

The gist of my question:  How do I add an HTMLEditor to a Pane (which is in the fxml file)?

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;

/**
 * Gets the controller's outputPane (the console in the gui)
 * @author Matt
 *
 */
public class OutputPanel{

    private static Pane pane;
    private static HtmlEditorWrap htmlEditor = new HtmlEditorWrap();

    private static final OutputPanel outputPanel = new OutputPanel();

    private OutputPanel(){}

    public static OutputPanel getInstance(){
        pane = Controller.getOutputPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(htmlEditor);
        return outputPanel;
    }

    public void clear(){
        //htmlEditor.setHtmlText();
    }

    public static void write(String text){
        htmlEditor.setHtmlText(text + "\n");
    }

}

class HtmlEditorWrap extends Rectangle{

    HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();

    public HtmlEditorWrap(){
        htmlEditor.setLayoutX(200);
        htmlEditor.setLayoutY(200);
        htmlEditor.setHtmlText("TESTING");
    }

    public void setHtmlText(String text){
        htmlEditor.setHtmlText(text);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually [HtmlEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) is a `Node`. Try adding it directly.
And how did you obtain an editor by extending `Rectangle`?

Comment: Thank you Ramazan.  I must have missed something there, as I just erased the wrapper class, put in an HTMLEditor and it worked.  Whatever I was doing before wasn't working.  Thanks again for pointing this out.